# Accessing characters with \symbol

Tags: unicode, font-encodings, external-files

I'm trying to use the \symbol{} command to output UTF8 haracters, but I can't get access any characters higher than 0x7E

The following code just outputs a tilde.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\symbol{'176}
\symbol{'304}

\end{document}
```

I'm clearly missing something trivial here, but I have no idea what it is.

(If you're wondering why I need this, it's because I need to pass the text to an external program that will embed that text into an SVG, and the quote as in "{a} is part of the syntax and can't be used for umlauts in German.)

Any tips would be great!

Comment: note you only need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` if you have an old latex

Answer (score 5):

You are using pdflatex (or latex) so all fonts are 8bit and have at most 256 characters `\symbol` takes a font slot not a unicode code point.

Even when it works, `\symbol` does not expand to a character usable in svg, it directly access the font for typesetting, just use `ä` it will write as an a-umlaut to the external file.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help with the external tool, which can't handle those special characters.. (I'm using a locally installed package called mscgentex, that calls the mscgen tool to create message sequence charts.) How does one find which symbols occupy which font slots?

Comment: @InformationEntropy sorry I can not guess what you mean. I was assuming your external tools could handle unicode so writing `ä` as `ä` should be all that is needed, why do you need to know the tex-specific font layout for the external SVG handling????

Comment: The idea is that the external tool generates an SVG that Latex uses its formatting for the text (like math formulas, etc.). However the tool cannot handle special characters, so I need to pass standard characters through it that will end up as UTF8 characters (like "\symbol('hexvalueSpecialCharacter") when being compiled by PDFLaTeX.